# How to Create a Multi-Colored Noise Shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, blender

I need a shader that takes 3 input colors and generates noise as seen below.
It is easy to achieve in Blender with the help of the "Noise Texture" and the "Color Ramp" nodes.

[image]
[image]

I've found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/toja/0e798c8dd54eb53ea0f0aeef414d16c9), which might solve my problem. But I wasn't able to configure the colors. And also the noise looks a lot "sharper" than the result in Blender.

Will I need to write my own shader for this or is there a simpler way to achieve this effect with ThreeJS?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write custom shaders. I recommend thebookofshaders.com for a nice introduction.

Comment: Although I am looking for a quick solution, this book seems to be really good. I guess I will need to invest some more time to understand shaders. Thank you @Marquizzo

Comment: [Three.js has a node system](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/nodes) but AFAICT [it doesn't have an official editor](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14244)  yet but there are several mentioned in that thread like [this one](https://dusanbosnjak.com/test/nodes/), and [this one](https://victhorlopez.github.io/editor/), and [this one](https://shaderfrog.com/app/) though no idea if any of those use the example node system from the three.js repo or make their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you need just two things:

1. Noise function in shader
2. A gradiental texture.

I chose FBM for noise and used `.onBeforeCompile()` to change a built-in material (Standard):

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cnvsGradient" width="300" height="50" style="position: absolute; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid aqua"/>

<script>
  // https://github.com/yiwenl/glsl-fbm/blob/master/3d.glsl
  const fbm = `
  #define NUM_OCTAVES 5

  float mod289(float x){return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;}
  vec4 mod289(vec4 x){return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;}
  vec4 perm(vec4 x){return mod289(((x * 34.0) + 1.0) * x);}

  float noise(vec3 p){
      vec3 a = floor(p);
      vec3 d = p - a;
      d = d * d * (3.0 - 2.0 * d);

      vec4 b = a.xxyy + vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      vec4 k1 = perm(b.xyxy);
      vec4 k2 = perm(k1.xyxy + b.zzww);

      vec4 c = k2 + a.zzzz;
      vec4 k3 = perm(c);
      vec4 k4 = perm(c + 1.0);

      vec4 o1 = fract(k3 * (1.0 / 41.0));
      vec4 o2 = fract(k4 * (1.0 / 41.0));

      vec4 o3 = o2 * d.z + o1 * (1.0 - d.z);
      vec2 o4 = o3.yw * d.x + o3.xz * (1.0 - d.x);

      return o4.y * d.y + o4.x * (1.0 - d.y);
  }


  float fbm(vec3 x) {
    float v = 0.0;
    float a = 0.5;
    vec3 shift = vec3(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OCTAVES; ++i) {
      v += a * noise(x);
      x = x * 2.0 + shift;
      a *= 0.5;
    }
    return v;
  }
  `;
</script>
<script type="module">
console.clear();

import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x444444);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

let g = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(2, 1, 5, 6, 64);

let pos = g.attributes.position;
let v = new THREE.Vector3();
let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
for(let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
  v.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
  let ratio = (v.y - (-2.5)) / 5;
  v.applyAxisAngle(axis, THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(60) * ratio);
  pos.setXYZ(i, v.x, v.y, v.z);
}
g.computeVertexNormals();

let uniforms = {
  tex: {
    value: setGradient()
  }
}
let m = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  metalness: 0.25,
  roughness: 0.75,
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.uniforms.tex = uniforms.tex;
    shader.vertexShader = `
      varying vec3 vPos;
      ${shader.vertexShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <begin_vertex>`,
      `#include <begin_vertex>
      //vPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
      vPos = vec3(position);
      `
    );
    //console.log(shader.vertexShader);
    shader.fragmentShader = `
      uniform sampler2D tex;
      varying vec3 vPos;
      ${fbm}
      ${shader.fragmentShader}      
    `.replace(
      `vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );`,
      `
      float d = fbm(vPos * 0.5);
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        d = fbm(vPos * (float(i) + 1.) * d);
      }

      vec3 col = texture(tex, vec2(d, 0.5)).rgb;
      vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( col, opacity );`
    );
    //console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  }
});
let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  o.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

function setGradient(){
  
  let canvas = document.getElementById('cnvsGradient');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0, 300,0);

  gradient.addColorStop(0.15, 'yellow');
  gradient.addColorStop(.5, 'red');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.85, 'blue');

  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  return new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );

}
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, I just have one problem: It does not accommodate to the size of the object. On some objects the noise is so large that the entire mesh has one color and on other objects the noise is so small that it's just "grain". How can I scale the noise to fit the object size?

Comment: @Flo Try to uncomment the line `//vPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;` and comment out `vPos = vec3(position);`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: @Flo If so, you can come to the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/), providing an example, that demonstrates the issue.